# How to get next certificate in chain

Tags: c, openssl, cryptoapi, wincrypt

I want to get parent certificate (or all certificates in chain for that matter) from Windows Certificate Store (assuming I know the location of the end certificate). I need to get each one in order to build my own custom `X509_STORE` (using *OpenSSL*).

I think the proper course of action would be:

1. obtain first certificate using `CertFindCertificateInStore` (done)
2. get the certificate chain using `CertGetCertificateChain` (done)
3. extract the certificates from chain (?)
4. for each certificate in chain, convert it using `d2i_X509` (done)

or

1. obtain first certificate using `CertFindCertificateInStore` (done)
2. get the parent certificate (if exists) (?)
3. convert it using `d2i_X509`, go to 2. (done)

Then create the store.

The question to answer is then - how to get the parent certificate or all certificates in chain using Windows Certificate Store? I'm probably missing some more or less occult function here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the `CertFindCertificateInStore` outputs a chain context, one can access it's members using the beautiful construction:

`chainContext->rgpChain[0]->rgpElement[iCertIndex]->pCertContext->pbCertEncoded`

where `iCertIndex` is between `0` (end-certificate) and `chainSize -1` (self-signed root certificate).